# How to overwrite default value of parameter in python __init__ method from class with two levels of inheritance:

Tags: python, inheritance

I need to overwrite the default parameter value of `__init__` method of a class that is on a three-party model which inherits from another three-party module, but I don´t want to copy all of the two levels of `__init__` parameters to my class just to do that, I think this is not a good practice, for a lot of reasons.

a simple sample code will be this:

```
from typing import Any, Callable



class A:
"class A from module 1"
    def __init__(self, param_A_1: Any, param_A_2: Any) -> None:
        self.param_A_1 = param_A_1
        self.param_A_2 = param_A_2


def func() -> str:
    return "Hi there!"

class B(A):
"class B from module 2"
    def __init__(
        self,
        param_A_1: Any,
        param_A_2: Any,
        paran_B_1: Any,
        param_B_2: Any,
        param_to_overwrite: Callable = func, 
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(param_A_1, param_A_2)
        self.paran_B_1 = paran_B_1
        self.param_B_2 = param_B_2
        self.param_to_overwrite = param_to_overwrite


def my_func() -> str:
    return "hello"


class C(B):
"my class"
    def __init__(
        self,
        param_A_1: Any,
        param_A_2: Any,
        paran_B_1: Any,
        param_B_2: Any,
        param_to_overwrite: Callable = my_func,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(self, param_A_1, param_A_2, paran_B_1, param_B_2, param_to_overwrite)
```

In the example code. `class A` and `class B` are three-party modules and `class C` is mine. this is a working example, but I'm looking for a way to avoid the repetition of the `__init__` method thinking on that the originals classes have a lot more parameter

I think this can be solved with a metaclass but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's hard to follow your example since it's not runnable.  Could you translate this into actual working code, and remove the parts that aren't important to what you're asking about?  I don't think seeing the `id_generator` implementation is necessary to understand/reproduce your `__init__` problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Use toy examples like `Class A`, `Class B`, etc to describe the behavior you want. It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Why overwrite a default parameter? Why not just pass the desired value in those cases?

Comment: I need to overwrite it because I don't want to instantiate every object from this class with the new `my_custom_default_id_generator`. I will edit my code

Comment: @Samwise I overwrite the code example

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good use case for `*args`:

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        param_to_overwrite: Callable = my_func,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, param_to_overwrite=param_to_overwrite, **kwargs)


assert C("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2").param_to_overwrite() == "hello"
assert C(param_A_1="A1", param_A_2="A2", paran_B_1="B1", param_B_2="B2").param_to_overwrite() == "hello"
```

The main downside of this compared to enumerating the args explicitly is that it's not type-safe, but since the original code is annotated with `Any` I assume that's not a concern.

Comment: Strictly speaking, type safety goes somewhat out the window once you introduce `super`, because you don't know that method `super().__init__` actually invokes at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, that's true ;). although  `Any` was just for the example code, the real implementation has well-defined typing

Comment: Some issue here, with this solution I can't use keywords arguments ... `C(param_A_1="A1", param_A_2="A2", param_B_1="B1", param_B_2="B2")` give an `unexpected keyword argument` error

Comment: add `**kwargs` then?  (this is why it's good to include a *complete* runnable example!)